# Compilation failed for package with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a `.cpp` file which can be compiled by `sourceRcpp()` successfully. Now I use `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` for it, and it generates the related directory. Then I run the code R CMD Install on the command line, but it showed a warning with an ERROR:

> compilation failed for package...

I'm Windows user and use RStudio. I've followed some advice and found the file `Makevars.win`, it has only one line

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

Maybe I need to add `Rcpp:::LdFlags()` or something. I've already install Rtools before because I can compile and install my own packages without using `Rcpp`.

Could you give me some advice how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in RStudio already do this:

1. File -> New Project -> New Directory -> R Package
2. **Important**: Switch the toggle in 'Create Package' from 'R Package' to 'R Package w/Rcpp'.
3. Build the package. It will work, just like `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.
4. Copy your source file into `src/`.
5. Build the package again. This will *automagically* run `compileAttributes()` for you which is what you failed to do manually.

All this is documented.

Comment: Of course it does.  You just missed the required step; see the 'Rcpp Attributes' vignette.